# Drupal 8 Taxonomy Terms same level

Tags: drupal, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I've a pretty simple Drupal 8 installation with this taxonomy:

- parent 1

  - child 1.1
  - child 1.2
  - child 1.3
- parent 2

  - child 2.1
  - child 2.2
- parent 3

  - child 3.1
  - child 3.2
  - child 3.3

When i'm on i.e. the child 1.2 taxonomy page (/taxonomy/terms/5) i would like to show child 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3 in a **block**.

I'm using **views** to accomplise this, but i can't get it to work. Tried to use a contextual filter on Taxonomy Parent, but no luck onfortunatly

Comment: Could you add the code that you have tried?

Comment: @MaartenDev, will a configuration export of the view do?

Comment: I'm looking for the Drupal View way to make something like:  SELECT taxonomy_name FROM terms WHERE term_parent = (this.term_parent)